# Do regulations require electronic checklists to be displayed on a cockpit screen or EFB?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, cockpit, software

As per regulation is it required to have the checklist (Normal and Emergency (drive by any alert))  as a part of the Cockpit Display System or EFB?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking here. Practically speaking, where else would an electronic checklist be displayed? Or are you simply asking if electronic checklists are required by regulation?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13951/62), at least for US regulations

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing in the CFRs requires an electronic checklist.  In fact, almost the reverse is true - from experience I know that part 135 operators need to justify the use of EFBs, and have it approved on their operating certificate.  (i.e. FAA doesn't force them, they must demonstrate that the devices meet applicable standards and basically ask for permission...)

And I don't know of any GA aircraft that have electronic checklists built into their displays, although I cannot say that the capability doesn't exist.

Although many airline and GA pilots fly with EFBs, a great many do not.  It would be a tremendous burden to owners and pilots, and a regulatory nightmare to attempt to enforce the use of electronic checklists.

And there is absolutely no compelling reason to do so... The battery will never run out on a laminated paper checklist, so why would you want to force someone to use a less reliable method?

Comment: FWIW, most of the newer Garmin PFDs have checklists built in. The C172S G1000 has them, for example, and that's been around since 2006. I assume the same is true for other manufacturers. There's [some evidence](https://lessonslearned.faa.gov/Northwest255/E_Checklists.pdf) - or at least some plausible arguments - that they're preferable to paper.

Comment: Part 121 matches your experience -- while we ***have*** the checklists (both normal and QRH) on our EFB, we're required to use the paper version during operations.  You can study the electronic version of the QRH, and of course the search/find capability is better on the e-reader, but paper is what we're required to ***use***.  (Of course, the 777 with EICAS & the checklist integrated into the aircraft software is a different story.)

Comment: @Ralph J, thanks for the concurrence.  I am on day three of Part 121 ground school!

Comment: Congrats!!! Very cool!